# How connect two computer to one an external hard disk drive?

Tags: hard-drive

I have two computers running windows 10. I wanted to connect both of them at the same time to an  external hard disk drive. Are there any hard disk drives that can accept two USB ports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a hard drive that can support two computer at the same time?

So, I would suggest to connect the external hard disk drive to one computer, then share the drive to the other computer. In Windows 10, you can easily do the folder sharing.

Comment: They could use some kind of NAS, but this also wouldn't be via USB either.